# Angular - how to do a dynamic alert with different type of errors?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

In my web app I am showing alerts for loading content and another alert when there is an error.

I am using AngularJS/AngularStrap

right now this is what I have:

```
var noLinesAlert = $alert({
  title: 'Sorry, no lines at this moment :(',
  container: '.no-lines-alert',
  type: 'danger',
  dismissable: false,
  show: false
}),

loaderAlert = $alert({
  content: 'Loading content. Please wait...',
  container: '.alerts-container',
  type: 'info',
  show: true
  });
```

and I am calling these alerts this way, example `noLinesAlert.show()` or `loaderAlert.hide()` and so on... but just imagine that I will have 4 more alerts for special cases, do I have to create those vars with the object inside every time or is there a way to do it more programmatically? and how.

Comment: What does it mean "more programmatically"? You are creating an alert in the code, not declaratively, how much more programmatically can it get?

Comment: what I do not want is to have a code for every single case, just call it and customize the attributes. or what can you tell me? the way I am doing it is the proper way?

Comment: You can create defaults, but ultimately you need to target a specific alert, no? So, you could create some wrapper service around it, but you have all the tools/hooks in your hands to do whatever you need.. In other words, you already have all the programmatic access required. Other than that, the question is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can store "default" settings for those 4 special cases in dedicated object, for example: `ALERTS_SETTINGS = { notice: {} }`, and then the call would be much more concise:

```
var noticeOptions = angular.extend(ALERTS_SETTINGS.notice, { title: "My custom property one" })
var notice = $alert(noticeOptions)
```

Using angular.extend you can override any default setting from the original object by those you provide in the second argument.

Comment: just what I need my friend. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For every alert the title, container, type, and show property changes. You need to give the program that information, so you can't do this any shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Make it dynamic by putting the $alert into a function. Allow the function to pass parameters to the $alert. Set the show property to true.

Call the function when needed. For example:

```
var displayAlert = function(alertTitle, className) {

    var alertOptions = {
       title: alertTitle,
       container: className,
       type: 'danger',
       dismissable: false,
       show: true
    };

    var alert = $alert(alertOptions);

}

// Call the function when needed
$scope.displayAlert('Sorry, no lines at this moment :(','.no-lines-alert')
```